# Flutter Duplicate GlobalKeys detected in widget tree

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error even though I have only one GlobalKey in my app. It is in my login screen. I have looked into the other solutions on StackOverflow, and it seems to be my login screen persisting. I am using CupertinoApp with a CupertinoTabView/CupertinoTabBar. Every thing is ok as long as I navigate within the tabs. But as soon as I navigate to a route over a tab, this error is thrown.

### Latest Update

Further investigation has lead me to believe that the error has nothing to with the login GlobalKey,  and everything to do with the Navigator. The error does not trigger when I set rootNavigator to true. For example, [this is a video](https://youtu.be/MJmY4R0ARxk) of Transition to a screen with a StreamBuilder without the rootNavigator.

The code:

```dart
          Navigator.of(
          context,
          //rootNavigator: true,
        ).push<void>(
          CupertinoPageRoute(
            builder: (ctx) => MatchResultsScreen(widget.match),
          ),
        ),
```

The error is triggered but the screen is rendered correctly.

Now here is a [video of the rootNavigator set to true.](https://youtu.be/joN5CtsIc_w)

The code:

```dart
          Navigator.of(
          context,
          rootNavigator: true,
        ).push<void>(
          CupertinoPageRoute(
            builder: (ctx) => MatchResultsScreen(widget.match),
          ),
        ),
```

Now there is no error, but the streambuilder does not render unless I do a hot reload.

This is clearly the cause of the issue. I have added a NavigatorState key each for the tabs. And each is rendered as a separate CupertinoTabView.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Flutter pro-tip: If you get an error, don't assume you actually have error. Restart first.

Comment: I think it has to do with `userSnapshot.hasData ? HomePage() : LoginScreen(),`. When does the Global Keys error show up? What steps have you taken when it occurs? Sounds to me like this code is recreating the `LoginScreen` component without disposing of a previous copy. So you end up with multiple instances in the stack. That's why the suggestions for Navigator. Navigator will handle the memory stack for you, if used properly.

Comment: Restarted multiple time. I have avoided this issue for weeks now. The issue is consistent.

Comment: Possibly, instead of creating the instances of `HomePage` and `LoginScreen` inline you could create them as properties of the class. `HomePage _homePage = new HomePage()` and `LoginScreen _loginScreen = new LoginScreen();` Then make sure you are using these instances instead: `userSnapshot.hasData ? _homePage : _loginScreen.`

Comment: @daddygames please do check the update.

Comment: if you made  ``` Navigator.of().pushReplacement()

Comment: @NimrSawafta Well the state is not maintained. HomePage has no user data to render any thing.

Comment: Can you share the code for LoginScreen. I'm guessing the problem is there.

Comment: Do you really need to pass those keys in contractors? just remove those constructors and have a test run. and let me know if its works.

Comment: @saiful It was one of the many last ditch efforts to resolve this issue. The keys make no difference.

Comment: @Mudassir I wish if I could get access of your project and test myself to fix the issue. Is that possible to get access?

Comment: @saiful email me at  mudassir.chapra at gmail. We can go from there.

Comment: This line `widget.loginKey.currentState.dispose();` in `HomePageState` doesn't look right. You should never call `dispose` on a `State`.

Comment: You've shared a lot of code. To get focused help, I think you'd have to remove everything that doesn't contribute to the problem, so you only a few lines of code left. There's a good chance you might even see what is the problem by yourself.

Comment: @sperksten It was a hail marry. It doesn't work. I have removed my from my code.

Comment: put the log before  `return CupertinoApp( ` and verify how many times it's triggered. if its trigger multiple time, try resue the LoginPage() instance

Comment: I have updated with a new update. I am close to a solution but I cant seem to get a hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to give a key to the

```dart
StreamBuilder(key:UniqueKey(),..)
```

Give the homepage and the login page a unique key too, you can create one like this:

```dart
 final myKey = GlobalKey();
```

and I think you keep building the **CupertinoApp** which created the issue.

so put it above the Streambuilder.
and the home make it a StreamBuilder(...)